# Inject custom Javascript callbacks into my plot.ly code within a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I'm using [plotly](https://plot.ly/) to make charts inside my Jupyter Notebook (Python).

It works great, I did a lot of funky stuff, but I'm missing one thing - I want to run my custom JavaScript code when someone clicks on a datum in my 3D scatter plot (copy content into the clipboard). I'm basically missing a `onclick` parameter where I could pass some arbitrary JS code.

There is a [tiny section on Click Events](https://plot.ly/python/click-events/) in the docs, but all the logic is implemented in JavaScript and it's not described how is it passed through.

How it looks in my dreams:

```
js_code = """ function myCallback( param ){...} """
trace = go.Scatter3d(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=z,
    mode='markers',
    customdata={"onclick": js_code}
)
```

In principal Plotly is a JavaScript library that just has Python API, so I'm sure it could execute my code if only I knew how to pass it through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few steps to get something similar to what you want:

- get the HTML div from plotly
- get the div id
- use the id to add an event handler using Plotly JS
- include Plotly JS

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

N = 10
random_x = np.random.randn(N)
random_y = np.random.randn(N)

trace = go.Scatter(
    x = random_x,
    y = random_y,
    mode = 'markers'
)

data = [trace]

# get the a div
div = plot(data, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
# retrieve the div id (you probably want to do something smarter here with beautifulsoup)
div_id = div.split('=')[1].split()[0].replace("'", "").replace('"', '')
# your custom JS code
js = '''
    <script>
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('{div_id}');
    myDiv.on('plotly_click',
        function(eventdata) {{  
            alert('CLICK!');
        }}
    );
    </script>'''.format(div_id=div_id)
# merge everything
div = '<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>' + div + js
# show the plot 
display(HTML(div))
```

Comment: This seems to be missing some things. import plotly.graph_objs as go, and import xxxx as plot?